# How to put a javascript array inside an arraylist of a class object?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I have the following code:

Advertisement class:

```
public class Advertisement {
    String name;
    String description;
    Date date;
    String city;
    String type;
    int rooms;
    int surface;
    int price;
    int userID;
    ArrayList<String> images;
    int httpStatus;
}
```

Advertisement spring controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean postAds(@RequestBody Advertisement newAd) {
        System.out.println(newAd.name+" "+" "+newAd.rooms+" "+newAd.surface+" "+newAd.price+" " + newAd.type+" "+newAd.description+newAd.images);

        return true;
    }
```

Angular controller:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: AppSettings.getApiUrl('/post'),
  data: {
    name: $scope.form.name,
    description: $scope.form.description,
    //city: $scope.form.city,
    rooms: $scope.form.rooms,
    surface: $scope.form.surface,
    price: $scope.form.price,
    type: $scope.form.selected,
    images: $scope.images,
    //userId: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  }
```

Now, when I make the post request to the server it gives the following error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception

How should I deserialize the $scope.images array into  images?

Comment: Are you sure that `$scope.images` an array of strings? You didn't show us that part of the code. And what do you mean by "images". That needs clarification. Do you mean a byte array? Or the variable name "images"?

Comment: Yes, $scope.images is an array of strings. I'm refering to the variable name images. This is $scope.images structure in javascript array:  ["https://i.imgur.com/7L10py5.png", "https://i.imgur.com/VZu52TH.jpg"]